# progress bar while creating excel file asp.net

Tags: asp.net, progress-bar

I've got a ASP.net page that create an excel file using eeplus library (http://epplus.codeplex.com/). my problem is that I create a really big file. It take times to be done and showed to the client. I search a way to show a kind of progressbar of the creation.

for the moment, the client click and wait til the file is created, so I cant really showed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is actually pretty complicated.  You might just want to show a spinning wheel gif or something and save yourself the headache.

However, if you're feeling adventurous, read on.

To use a progress bar, you need to create a way to measure how much % complete your task is.  This usually involves some kind of incrementer that gets measured against the total number of rows/column/whatever that you're creating.  I don't know what language you're using, so here's some pseudo to help you out:

```
var totalRows     = 100;
var processedRows = 0;
var progress      = 0;

while( processedRows < totalRows ){

   Process_A_Row();

   processRows++;
   progress = processedRows / totalRows;

   StoreProgressSomewhereForPolling();
}
```

So there's your basic mechanism for tracking progress.  On the client, you'll need to set up a way to poll the value of the progress variable.  This gets messy because you'll quickly learn that you need a way to isolate the progress variable for every individual request.  Its up to you how to implement this -- there are lots of ways to do it.  One solution I saw stored the progress value in a static dictionary keyed by username so that it could be easily polled by the client with webmethods.

Comment: Another option instead of polling could be to push the progress directly to the client, for .net have look at the SignalR library.

Comment: @jods: As I understand it, SignalR doesn't really "push" so much as it is polled...at least where websockets are not involved.  You are right, though -- it makes bi-directional communication scenarios like this one much, much easier :)

Comment: Yes it abstracts the mechanism of bi-directional communication. But it actually has several layers of fallbacks if web sockets are not available: server-sent events, forever frame... and of course ultimately polling.

Comment: I look at SignalR. Before, I was more thinking to create an intermediate page. she create the file step by step, showing the progress and keeping the data into session var (too big for viewstate). after finish, call the excel.aspx who will use the session.

Comment: I also thought about ajax, looking at a page who check the progress of the creation.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be to use the Ajax.NET `UpdateProgress` control.  Just display a GIF that spins while the server is processing.